# How to debug a countdown timer on each tick in android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have a countdown timer and a progress bar

```
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        progress = (int) (millisUntilFinished/1000);

        progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getMax()-progress);

        progressBar.setText(String.valueOf(progress)+" "+"secs");



    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        //STOP COUNTER
        myCountDownTimer.cancel();


    }
}
```

How to debug and examine each progress value in android studio, because I have initial value 30 it goes smoothly to 25 then to 28 then to 21 , it goes up and down!!

What I should do?

Answer (score 0):

You have just to put 
`log.e("your tag","millisUntilFinished="+millisUntilFinished);`  on your onTick methode.

or toogle a breakpoint instead and run the app on debut mode (shift+F9) ,and you will see the value of each variable on earch on tick iteration .